# Do a Windows Command on remote server using Gitlab CI Runner

Tags: command-line, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I try to do a `iisreset` command on Windows remote server from a Gitlab Runner.
This is my gitlab-ci.yml :

```
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    script:
        - [...copy windows file...]
        - iisreset
     when: manual
```

But `iisreset` command is executed on Gitlab Runner and not on remote server.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Is the gitlab-runner on the Windows remote server? is the gitlab-runner using a shell executer?

Comment: Yes is a shell executor but my runner is not the remote server, is another server

Comment: Sounds like you need to run an ssh/winrm command remotely from your gitlab-runner -> remote server to run the `iisreset` command